# HTML Emails: The Use Case for Nested Tables

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I'm relatively new to HTML Email Development, and I'm trying to wrap my head around nested tables, specifically WHEN to nest a table, create a tr tag pair, or add a td tag pair.
Below is a code snippet from a real-world example of an HTML Email located at this URL to illustrate the basis of my confusion: https://reallygoodemails.com/emails/save-30-for-our-winter-sale/live

```html
<body style="margin:0; padding:0; min-width:100%; background-color:transparent;">
    <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;">Our Winter Sale gets better</div>
    <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;">&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;
      &nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;&nbsp;&zwnj;</div>
    <table width="100%" class="body" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation">
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:transparent;">
          <table width="100%" class="Wrapper" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="background-color:transparent; border-top-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-color: #222222;">

                <!--[if(gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 600px;" role="presentation"> <tr> <td align="center"><![endif]-->
                <table width="100%" class="Container" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="max-width:600px;" role="presentation">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="background-color:#000000">
                      <table width="100%" class="Column-1 " cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center">
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" role="presentation">
                              <tr class="text">
                                <td style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; border-width: 0px; border-style: none; font-family: 'soehne-web-buch', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; color: #222222; line-height: 1.5; text-align: center">
                                  <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"><span style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family:neusanextpro-condensedlight,arial,helvetica,sans-serif"><span style="letter-spacing:2px"><i><a href="http://enews.saxxunderwear.com/q/R9jim0BXYC7rm0Xq39_vyPg_M10yCZNUNEHZcLOJbWF0dGhld0ByZWFsbHlnb29kZW1haWxzLmNvbcOIPt_chqcYdIroPVYZqAC1RDbf1A" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;" target=
"_blank" title="SET UP AN ACCOUNT TO BE ELIGIBLE FOR FREE SHIPPING" data-link-name="WINTER SALE: 30% OFF.">WINTER SALE: 30% OFF.</a>&nbsp;FREE SHIPPING AVAILABLE WITH AN ACCOUNT. <a href="http://enews.saxxunderwear.com/q/fyo89AKFHe5xD0XpfKsqmahpuN9CevUgh5UZcOJbWF0dGhld0ByLZWFsbHlnb29kZW1haWxzLmNvbcOIQzNjZV5Pcr0eVO1_pLw6d0szaw" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" title=
"" data-link-name="LEARN MORE"><u>LEARN MORE</u></a><a href="http://enews.saxxunderwear.com/q/YSTmkctvfNwLo0XGaNue3OjIVQObNHs2jWDZcOJbWF0dLGhld0ByZWFsbHlnb29kZW1haWxzLmNvbcOIlmZZNFUuc7bp4ycY1kS-E55mUQ" style="color:#ffffff;text-decoration:underline;" target="_blank" title="" data-link-name="."><u>.</u></a></i></span></span></p>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
```

There are SIX tables here and—although I understand what Table 1 and Table 6 are doing—the other four tables are confusing.

- Table 2 looks like it defines the wrapper for the page. But doesn’t Table 1 do that already? If so, why is it there?
- Table 3 and Table 4 look like they both act as the main container for the HTML email template, since they both define the width of the main table. But I don’t understand why Table 3 is necessary when Table 4 specifies the same width of 600px?
- Table 5 has a class of “Column-1”, but there isn’t a class labelled “Column-1” in the stylesheets found in the head of the document, so why is it there?

These observations, among others, have made me realize that there is a TON of variation in HTML Email Development whenever nested tables are concerned. So much so that it makes it difficult to derive a general rule of thumb for table, tr, and td use. But from what I can see:

- Tables are used for cutting the page into blocks and specifying the size of said blocks.
- Tr tag pairs are used for defining separate sections in an HTML Email Template.
- Td tag pairs are used for content placement (in child tables) or content formatting (in parent tables).

Can anyone validate my observations or, better yet, give me a more detailed explanation of WHEN to make a new table, tr, or td in the context of HTML Email Development?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Please correct me if I am wrong on any of my observations. I truly want to learn the nuances of this field to the best of my ability.

Answer (score 6):

The one and only reason we still need to use tables in HTML emails today is… *Outlook*. And more specifically: *Outlook on Windows*. And even more specifically: *Outlook on Windows, versions 2007 and up*.

In 2007, Microsoft decided to change Outlook’s rendering engine from Internet Explorer to… Word. And Word is not very good at rendering HTML and CSS. Not only does it only support partial CSS from up to 2007 (so no flexbox, no `border-radius`, etc.), but it usually does a poor job at what it is supposed to support. For example, the `padding` property works, but not on `<div>` elements.

With time, I’ve come to use tables only in the following cases:

- To set a fixed width on an element (using `<table style="width:600px">`).
- To set two elements side by side (using two siblings `<td>`).
- To set a `padding`, `background-color` or a `border` style.

Back to your post and example, all your observations on tables 1-6 seem right to me. The code looks really bloated (with lots of unecessary styles too). My guess is this comes from the build process of this email. Either it was coded manually from a previous template that needed all these tables and the developer wasn't adventurous enough to remove any of them. Or maybe the email is the output of an email builder (which very often add way too many code because their goal is to cover as many options as possible with a similar output code). The second option seems more possible to me considering the code from the text (with all the nested `<span><span><u><i><a>`).

I tried to recode the sample you copied above. And here’s what it looks like.

```html
<!--[if mso]><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:600px;" role="presentation"><tr><td><![endif]-->
  <div style="margin:0 auto; width:100%; max-width:600px;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%; background:#000;">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding:10px;">
          <p style="margin:0; text-align:center; letter-spacing:2px; color:#fff; font:italic 12px/18px neusanextpro-condensedlight, sans-serif;">
            <a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank" style="color:#fff; text-decoration:none;">WINTER SALE: 30% OFF.</a>&nbsp;FREE SHIPPING AVAILABLE WITH AN ACCOUNT. <a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank" style="color:#fff; text-decoration:underline;">LEARN MORE.</a>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!--[if mso]></td></tr></table><![endif]-->
```

Only two tables are needed. The first one is specifically for Outlook inside a conditional comment. It is used to set the width of the container. The second one is use for both the `background:#000;` and the `padding:10px`.

If you want to learn more about Outlook and HTML emails in general, I wrote the following posts:

- [Email Coding Guidelines](https://github.com/hteumeuleu/email-guidelines)
- [Making sense of Outlook’s rendering engine](https://www.hteumeuleu.com/2020/outlook-rendering-engine/)

And I can’t recommend enough the [#emailgeeks Slack](https://email.geeks.chat/) and its *#email-code* channel filled with passionate email developers helping and learning from each others.

Comment: 35 lines of code works the same with 13 lines. This is why I love emails and helping fix code issues. (you beat me to it)

Answer (score -1):

Generally in HTML, using tables for creating layout is considered a bad practice, but I guess in email HTML it is more acceptable because support for old applications is very important so using modern layout tools is problematic.

Simply putting, `<table></table>` tags define an entire table (or table layout), `<tr>` tags define a table row, and `<td>` tags define a single cell within a row. You can never put content directly inside a row, it's always table -> row -> cell even if it's a row with only one cell.

A nested table inside a cell allows cutting that cell into smaller areas.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to write your answer, but I'm already aware of the basic function of each tag. My confusion lies with their use case in the context of HTML Email Development, namely WHEN should a new nested table be written versus a new set of tr or td tags.